# how to duplicate one row in table 1 and multiple associated rows from table 2 using php

Tags: php, sql, duplicates, row, multiple-tables

I have a table with cars. Each car has one, or more, tuning stages located in another table.
In the table with tuning stages; There is a car identifier: [cId] = car id.

First I duplicate the car and store the new generated id from `mysql_insert_id()` into `$new_carId`.
Then I fetch all associated tuning stages, based on the car identifier [cId], and do the same as I did with the car, but in a `while()`-loop.

Now the new duplicated stages has the [cId] from the old car.
I now need to replace [cId] with whatever id stored in `$new_carId` so the duplicated stages gets assigned to the new car.

The way I see it; I have two options:
Either make it happen directly in the `INSERT`-query or
do an sql `UPDATE` at the end of the `while()`-loop.

here is my code so far:

```
/**
 *  Duplicate an existing car with associated tuning stage:
 *  Each car may have more than one associated tuning stage located in a separate table. 
 *  We need to make sure all stages is duplicated as well, and assigned to the new car.
 *
 *  [cId] car id.
 *
 *  debug() is a personal debugging function.
 */
    if (isset($_POST['duplicate_car'])){
    #   duplicate the car.
        $orgCar_id = (int)mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['orgCar_id']);  //  ID of the car we make the duplicate from.
        $sql_car = 'INSERT INTO TUNE_cars (make, model, chassis, motor, motorkode, orgEff, orgNm, year, options, note)
            SELECT make, model, chassis, motor, motorkode, orgEff, orgNm, year, options, note FROM TUNE_cars WHERE cId = '.$orgCar_id;
        //  debug($sql_car);
        $qry_car = mysql_query($sql_car);
        $new_carId = (int)mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_insert_id());  //  We need to attach this ID to the new duplicated tuning stages.
    //
    /**
     *  Duplicate any associated tuning stages:
     *  We need to fetch all stages associated with the old car,
     *  duplicate them aswell, and attach them to the new car. 
     *
     *  [sId] stage id
     *  [cId] car id. This connects the stages to a given car.
     */
        #   fetch all stages associated with the old car.
            $sql_stages = 'SELECT sId FROM TUNE_stages WHERE cId = '.$orgCar_id;
            //  debug($sql_stages);
            $qry_stages = mysql_query($sql_stages);
        //
        #   duplicate the stages.
            while($get_stage = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_stages)){
                $sql_dup_stage = 'INSERT INTO TUNE_stages (cId, stage, stageHp, stageNm, stagePrice, stageMethod, stageDyno, sinfo, snote)
                SELECT '.$new_carId.', stage, stageHp, stageNm, stagePrice, stageMethod, stageDyno, sinfo, snote FROM TUNE_stages WHERE sId = '.$get_stage['sId'];
                //  debug($sql_dup_stage);
                $qry_dup_stage = mysql_query($sql_dup_stage);
            //
            }
        //
    /**/
    }
/**/
```

As you can see; I used the last method:
I did an `UPDATE` at the end of the `while()`-loop.

I do believe this could be done simpler and are open for suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the second update. Change

```
$sql_dup_stage = 'INSERT INTO TUNE_stages (cId, stage, stageHp, stageNm, stagePrice, stageMethod, stageDyno, sinfo, snote)
            SELECT cId, stage, stageHp, stageNm, stagePrice, stageMethod, stageDyno, sinfo, snote FROM TUNE_stages WHERE sId = '.$get_stage['sId'];
```

to:

```
$sql_dup_stage = 'INSERT INTO TUNE_stages (cId, stage, stageHp, stageNm, stagePrice, stageMethod, stageDyno, sinfo, snote)
            SELECT \''.$new_carId.'\', stage, stageHp, stageNm, stagePrice, stageMethod, stageDyno, sinfo, snote FROM TUNE_stages WHERE sId = '.$get_stage['sId']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  
Tried putting `$new_carId` before `SELECT` and leave out [cId] inside of it. But that didn't work.

Comment: My mistake. You should put quotes around string value in SQL. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I updated my first post with your suggestion.  
I'm not on the same computer, but I think it was like this and it worked perfectly...  
So thanks again...